# How to relate data to a specific row in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

What I basically want is to show the user's name in the first tableView but have a disclosure indicator (segue) to go to a second tableView which will show the history of the selected user. I know how to load data into a table and how to segue from one row to the detail table but I just don't know how to show different data for each user. I know this may be out of my scope of knowledge at the moment but I would like to give it a try.

1- What would be the best way to store the data for each user (history), an array per user?
2- How can I relate data to a specific user so it loads when the user's name is touched?
3- How can I capture the row being selected?

[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, you shouldn't worry about it being outside of your scope of knowledge, as that's how people learn.  You will need to do some amount of work, however, and that part can be a little difficult.

Luckily, what you're trying to do is a very well documented function and Xcode even provides a template for master -> detail views.

Check out this wonderful tutorial by Ray Wenderlich on creating a simple master-detail application: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/ios-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-part-1

His other tutorials will also be immensely helpful to beginning iOS development: http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links, I will follow the tutorial from raywenderlich.com.

Comment: No problem :).  If it helps, maybe mark it as answered? :P